# Counting number of nodes in tree in ocaml

Tags: tree, ocaml

I'm writing a program that should count the number of nodes in a given tree in ocaml.

```
type 'a tree = Node of 'a * 'a tree list

let count tree = 
    let rec visit node =
      let (_,list_of_children) = node in
      let rec help list1 = 
        match list1 with 
        | [] -> 0
        | h::t -> (help t) + (visit h)  in
     (List.length list_of_children) + 1 + help list_of_children in
    visit tree
```

However, the code doesn't work. Here's what the compiler says:

> File "liscie5.ml", line 10, characters 44-60: Error: This expression
>   has type 'a list
>          but an expression was expected of type ('b * 'a list) list
>
> (Line 10: (List.length list_of_children) + 1 + help list_of_children
>   in).

Any ideas what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You should learn and use `List.fold_left`. I recommend re-implementing `List.length` using `List.fold_left` and then modifying it to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem I see is this:

```
let (_,list_of_children) = node in
```

Presumably `node` is of type `'a tree`. Thus it will look like `Node (value, children)`. But this line of code treats it as a generic pair of OCaml values `(a, b)`. It would help to write this instead:

```
let Node (_,list_of_children) = node in
```

There are more concise ways to write this, but it should help make a little progress. No doubt there are other (possibly similar) problems.